# How to use ffmpeg command without any codec?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, raw-input

I am using the following command to create an mp4 container, input in a raw file, and the problem I have is FFmpeg apparently trying to encode me in H264. Is there a way to tell FFmpeg not to use any codec? that is, how do I use FFmpeg without compressing anything? Thanks!

Command statement i'm using:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pixel_format rgb24 -video_size 160x120 -framerate 24 -i file out.mp4
```

Output:[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rawvideo to mp4 container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60227384/rawvideo-to-mp4-container)

Comment: It is possible with AVI output video container: `ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pixel_format rgb24 -video_size 160x120 -framerate 24 -i file -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 out.avi`

Comment: @Rotem Thank you very much if it worked for me, but now I have the following question.   .avi does a follow the mpeg4 format?

Comment: AVI is a container, MP4 is a container, and mpeg4 is a codec (or codecs). I think the answer is no, but it's difficult to answer without understanding the context. mpeg4 does not support video without compressing.